# Moving buttons in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I am making a site that has a grid of buttons, I was wondering what the best way is to make those buttons re-organizeable. I would like to keep the layout of the grid just swap positions of the buttons via a drag and drop function. I'm assuming there is some javascript/jquery way of doing this but I'm a little rusty.

Comment: This has nothing to do with buttons, [Look here](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to)

Comment: Well I'm just using buttons as my objects, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/), it is simple to use.

Just use this function :

```
$(function() {
   $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
   $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

And don't forget to link the external script and css.

Here's an example : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCBrh/7/).

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend jQuery UI as an easy way to do it. Check the Sortable interaction http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: I assume it does, but does sortable work on mobile devices as well? I couldn't find it in the mobile API

Answer (score 0):

For that you need something like draggable and snap to that particualar area where the drag should stop.

You can refer to [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) for it.

To suit your needs perfectly, here is the [actual drag and drop to the snap object](http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/card-game.html)

Hope this helps now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use
[**Isotope**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)
if you wanna sort then by category and as an extra feature this make it possible to have different sizes

You could go for the version like with jquery but with out jquery:
[**Masonry Vanilla**](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/)

This also allow browser resizing